# How to conditional import & re-render app.js

Tags: reactjs, render

I use some conditional import for scss files. It's used to handle dark-mode. It's OK on load.

```
const App = () => {
const [mode,setMode] = useState('DARK');
//const [CHOSEN_THEME, setCHOSEN_THEME] = useState(localStorage.getItem('TYPE_OF_THEME') || 'LIGHT');
console.log('app',mode);
const ThemeSelector = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                {(mode === 'LIGHT') && <LightTheme/>}
                {(mode === 'DARK') && <DarkTheme/>}
            </React.Suspense>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
return (<>
    <ThemeSelector>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                ...
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </ThemeSelector>
    </>
)};
const rootElement = document.querySelector('#App');
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, rootElement);
```

In navbar, I have a button which sets "mode" in localstorage and updates mode var.

```
const handleDarkmode = () => {
    //do some stuffs
    props.setMode('DARK');
    localStorage.setItem('TYPE_OF_THEME', 'DARK');
```

localstorage is set correctly and mode is updated in app.js. My problem is that theme selector is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try transfer `mode` as a props of `ThemeSelector` component like this:

```
const ThemeSelector = ({children, mode}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                {(mode === 'LIGHT') && <LightTheme/>}
                {(mode === 'DARK') && <DarkTheme/>}
            </React.Suspense>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
```

and in your App: `<ThemeSelector mode={mode}>`

you also should move define `ThemeSelector` out of `App` component too

Answer (score 0):

it works only once when I click on my button.

```
const LightTheme = React.lazy(() => import('./assets/LightTheme'));
const DarkTheme = React.lazy(() => import('./assets/DarkTheme'));
const ThemeSelector = ({children, mode}) => {
    console.log('theme_selector',mode);
    return (
        <>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
                {(mode === 'LIGHT') && <LightTheme/>}
                {(mode === 'DARK') && <DarkTheme/>}
            </React.Suspense>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
import fakeBackend from './helpers/AuthType/fakeBackend'
const App = () => {
    const [mode,setMode] = useState('DARK');
    //const [CHOSEN_THEME, setCHOSEN_THEME] = useState(localStorage.getItem('TYPE_OF_THEME') || 'LIGHT');
    console.log('app',mode);

    return (<>
        <ThemeSelector mode={mode}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    {authRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                        <Authmiddleware
                            path={route.path}
                            layout={NonAuthLayout}
                            component={route.component}
                            key={idx}
                            isAuthProtected={false}
                            mode={mode}
                            setMode={setMode}
                        />
                    ))}

                    {userRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                        <Authmiddleware
                            path={route.path}
                            layout={VerticalLayout}
                            component={route.component}
                            key={idx}
                            isAuthProtected={false}
                            exact
                            mode={mode}
                            setMode={setMode}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </ThemeSelector>
        </>
    )
};
```

on line 4, mode is updated for each click but not themeSelector

Comment: Can you share your current code on codesandbox or jsfiddle?